# How To Set Default Wallpaper As Login Screen Wallpaper [Automatically]?

Tags: login-screen, desktop-background

I`m Unable To Set The Login Screen Wallpaper Of My Custom Wallpaper Is There Any Working Tool Which Changes Easily Without Any Bugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Ubuntu Tweaks.  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Another way of doing it, is right click on the desktop, and click Change Desktop Background.
[image]
Click the + sign
[image]
Browse, and choose the image, and click open
[image]
The desktop background has changed with the new image
[image]
This is the login screen, with the new image applied.
[image]

Comment: I Installed It But Its Not Working When I`m Trying To set the default background as login screen it wont change it just uses the default wallpaper of ubuntu

Comment: What are the permissions on the file you're trying to use?

Comment: I cant get you The File I`m Using Had No Permissions Normal File

Answer (score 1):

You all are not understandig what the guy wants. He wants exactly the opposite of what you're telling him. He wants the login screen with a DIFFERENT picture, not the same as his desktop wallpaper.

To solve your little problem, install UbuntuTweaks as Mitch said. Open it, go to the Tweaks tab and you'll see the option to change the login screen.

To install Ubuntu Tweaks:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, with 'Wallch'. install it from software center. every time when you change your desktop background, it will be autamatically your login background also.